# Select2 Add New Tag if no result returned in search

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller, tags, jquery-select2

I have dropdown list where , after typing 2 or more symbols it starts to search in base nad returns values . if none is searched i want user to be able to add that tag as new one. here is my code so far

```
    $("#tags,#TagId").select2(
    {
        allowClear: true,
        ajax: {
            url: "/Entry/ReadSelect2DataMulti",
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term,
                    page: params.page || 1
                };
            },
            processResults: function (data, params) {
                params.page = params.page || 1;
                return {
                    results: data
                };
            },
            cache: true,
            error: function (xhr, textStarus, error) {
            }
        },
        minimumInputLength: 2,
        placeholder: "აირჩიეთ პოზიცია",
        templateResult: function (state) {
            var result = '<div class="pos-template">' + '<span title=""><b>' + state.text + '</b></span>';
            if (state.content != null && state.content != '') {

                var tags = state.content.split(",");
                for (i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                    result = result + '<span class="pos-tag">' + tags[i] + '</span>';
                }
            } else {

            }
            result = result + '</div></div>';

            return $(result);
        },
        createSearchChoice: function (term, data) {
            if ($(data).filter(function () {
                return this.text.localeCompare(term) === 0;
            }).length === 0) {
                return { id: term, text: term };
            }
        },
        language: {
            noResults: function () {
                return "პოზიცია ვერ მოიძებნა";
            },
            inputTooShort: function () {
                return "შეავსეთ მინიმიმ 2 სიმბოლო";
            },
            loadingMore: function () {
                return 'იტვირთება...';
            },
            searching: function () {
                return 'იფილტრება...';
            }
        }
    }
);
```

But this createSearch doesnt do anything.

```
    <div class="form-group">
    <select multiple="multiple" class="form-control" id="tags" style="width: 400px;"></select>
</div>
```

this is my div part . any suggestions ?